# count issue in c (visual studio)

Tags: c, pointers

this is the function code:

```
void statistics(int arr[], int n, int *positive, int *even, int *doubledigit)
{
    int i = 0, countP = 0, countE = 0, countD = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > 0)
            countP++;

        if((arr[i] % 2) == 0)
            countE++;

        if(abs(arr[i]) >= 10 && abs(arr[i]) < 100)
            countD++;
    }

    *positive = countP;
    *even = countE;
    *doubledigit = countD;
}

void main()
{
    //  double mat[size][size];
    int *positive = NULL, *even = NULL, *DoubleDigit = NULL;
    int arr4[] = {1, 3, 5, -45, 8, 8, 60, 800};
    int soa = sizeof(arr4);
    statistics(arr4, soa, &positive, &even, &DoubleDigit);
}
```

the problem is that the result of the even numbers is 28:

why is it 28?? it should count the even numbers...
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS2us.png

Comment: `sizeof` counts bytes, not 'number of integers'.  So, you are telling the function to examine 32 integers in your 8 integer array.  It is reading garbage and coming up with garbage.

Comment: See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336)

Comment: Note that your compiler was warning you about type mismatches (between the function definition and the function call). Pay attention to the compiler; it is trying to help you.  At this stage in your career, assume the compiler is right; it knows a lot more about C than you do.  Even later on when you've learned a lot more about C, the compiler will be right more often than you are when the two of you disagree about whether some C code is valid.

Answer (score 4):

First the return type of `main()` should be `int`.

Secondly for some reason you are passing the addresses of `int` pointers (that are initialised to NULL) to your function. Just pass `int*` parameters to your function like you should be.

Thirdly, `sizeof` returns the size of the array in bytes. You want to iterate over the number if elements in the array, not the byte count. Therefore you need to divide the byte count by the number of bytes in each element (`sizeof(int)`).

Try this instead

```
int main()
{
  int positive =0, even = 0, DoubleDigit = 0;
  int arr4[] = { 1, 3, 5, -45, 8, 8, 60, 800 };
  int soa = sizeof(arr4)/sizeof(int);
  statistics(arr4, soa, &positive, &even, &DoubleDigit);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Memory *addresses* of some *value-buckets* are stored in these:

```
int *positive = NULL, *even = NULL, *DoubleDigit = NULL;
```

You want to declare actual *value-buckets* where to store the results/values, not the storage for *addresses*, so change to:

```
int positive = 0, even = 0, DoubleDigit = 0;
```

---

Also, you want the number integers in `arr4`, so change to:

```
int soa = sizeof(arr4) / sizeof(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `main()` function: `positive` `even` `DoubleDigit` has been a pointer. However you pass their address to function `statistics()`.

```
statistics(arr4, soa, &positive, &even, &DoubleDigit);
```

is equal to

```
statistics(int arr[],int soa,int **positive, int **even, int **DoubleDigit);
```

but you declare it as

```
statistics(int arr[], int n, int *positive, int *even, int *doubledigit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
void statistics( const int arr[], int n, int *positive, int *even, int *doubledigit )
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( arr[i] > 0 ) ++*positive;

        if ( arr[i] % 2 == 0 ) ++*even;

        if ( abs( arr[i] ) >= 10 && abs( arr[i] ) < 100 ) ++*doubledigit;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int positive = 0, even = 0, DoubleDigit = 0;
    int arr4[] = { 1, 3, 5, -45, 8, 8, 60, 800 };

    int soa = sizeof( arr4 ) / sizeof( *arr4 );
    statistics( arr4, soa, &positive, &even, &DoubleDigit );
}
```

As for your code then you declared pointers

```
int *positive = NULL, *even = NULL, *DoubleDigit = NULL;
```

but they do not point to actual memory.

You call the function parsing addresses of the pointers themselves

```
statistics(arr4, soa, &positive, &even, &DoubleDigit);
```

that is for example expression `&positive` has type `int **` while the corresponding parameter of the function

```
void statistics( const int arr[], int n, int *positive, int *even, int *doubledigit )
```

is declared as having type `int *`

Expression `sizeof(arr4)` yields the size in bytes of array `arr4` while you have to pass the numjber of elements in the array.

Function main shall have return type `int`

```
int main( void )
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Please explain the changes.